# headroom.js with zurb foundation

Tags: javascript, sass, zurb-foundation

Trying to implement `header.js` into my zub foundation site, but no matter what js style I try to write (directly off http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) the header stays fixed to the top of the page.

**My html:**

```
<header id="header" class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav data-topbar role="navigation" class="top-bar sticky">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1 href="#" class="a"></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#header">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
          <li><a href="#our-team">our team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact-form">contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#register" style="color:#056fb7;">register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

**My js:**

```
(function() {
var header = new Headroom(document.querySelector("#header"), {
    tolerance: 5,
    offset : 205,
    classes: {
      initial: "animated",
      pinned: "slideDown",
      unpinned: "slideUp"
    }
});
header.init();
};
```

**My Sass:**

```
.headroom
    transition: transform 200ms linear !important
.headroom--pinned
    display:block
    transform: translateY(0%) !important
.headroom--unpinned
    display:none
    transform: translateY(-100%) !important
```

Comment: just use `#header{position: fixed; } or .header {position: fixed; } ` in your css. To make changes in js try using the simple `$('.header').css({position: 'fixed'});` inside your document ready function

Comment: i have this <header id="header" class="navigation-section show-for-medium-up contain-to-grid fixed"> but the header still doesn't disappear